# Invoke jQuery EasyTooltips on Dynamically Created Anchors

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I think the answer to my problem is to use delegate() but I'm not entirely sure - and need a pointer...

I am using the rather brilliant EasyTooltip plugin to add simple tooltips to all the anchors within a div.

This all works fine with the below executed on document.ready():

```
jQuery(".profile-popup").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).easyTooltip({
        useElement: "toolTipLikingIt",
        xOffset: -100,
        yOffset: -20
    });
});
```

But, I am also elsewhere in the script adding new anchors to this div in some circumstances.
I did try adding to the event that creates the anchors a call to the same .easyTooltip() function but this failed to work.

Can anyone suggest the solution?

The plugin is from: http://cssglobe.com/post/4380/easy-tooltip--jquery-plugin

Thanks!

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, switching to delegate should solve your issues since it reacts to dynamically added elements. Here's an article that was written a couple months ago that should give you all the info you need on choosing the correct method:

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: Hi Chords,Thanks for the second opinion. I'm probably being very stupid - but looking at delegate/live it seems to want to attach a click/hover etc event. But the plugin for EasyTooltip sets up the hover event itself... could you give an example?

Comment: Hm, I would try something along the lines of: `$('element').delegate('selector', 'click', function(){ $(this).easyTooltip(); });`